# Nonlinear complex ODE system modeling modified harmonic oscillator coupled to quantum harmonic oscillator

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

I'm using `NDSolve` for a system of non-linear ODEs. Here is my code

```
g1 = 5;
g2 = 1;
tbar = 50; 
n = 20;
(*declare matrices*)
d0 = IdentityMatrix[n];
d1 = Table[If[i == j, i, 0], {i, 0, n - 1}, {j, 0, n - 1}];
d2 = Table[If[i == j - 1, Sqrt[j], 0], {i, 0, n - 1}, {j, 0, n - 1}];
d3 = Table[If[i == j + 1, Sqrt[j + 1], 0], {i, 0, n - 1}, {j, 0, n - 1}];

(*declare initial variables*)
{x0, p0} = {0, 0};
initc = a[0] == (x0 + I*p0)/Sqrt[2];
{expx0, expp0} = {1, 1};
\[Alpha] = (expx0 + I*expp0)/Sqrt[2];
initq = c[0] == Chop[Normalize@Table[\[Alpha]^i/Sqrt[i!], {i, 0, n - 1}]];

(*differential equations*)

sol = NDSolve[{a'[t] == -I (g1*a[t] + g2/2 c[t].(d2 + d3).Conjugate[c[t]]), 
    c'[t] == -I*c[t].(d1 + 0.5*d0 + g2*(Re@a[t]) (d2 + d3)), 
    initc, initq}, {a, c}, {t, 0, tbar}];

(*plotting*)
asol[t_] := a[t] /. sol[[1]]
csol[t_] := c[t] /. sol[[1]]
Plot[{Re@asol[t], Im@asol[t]}, {t, 0, tbar}, PlotRange -> All]
```

I want to be able to get reliable results for this system for a range of values of the parameters $g1$ and $g2$. The problem arises when I use values which make the non-linear term (the second term) in the first equation large. For example, when I use $g1=5, g2=1$, the solutions are good but when I use $g1=0.5, g2=1$, I can already see that there is something wrong (the values are too large). So essentially the problem seems to be in the ratio $g2/g1$ and I suspect this is due to the non-linearity and perhaps something goes wrong with the NDSolve algorithm (the run times are also much longer for the problematic cases).
Is there a way I can make this code work for a larger parameter range?

EDIT: what do I mean by "too large"? I mean the values of `Re@asol` and `Im@asol` being large, to see why this is an issue I need some context for this system. This is a problem from physics of a modified harmonic oscillator (MHO) coupled to a quantum harmonic oscillator (QHO). Energy conservation should hold for this system i.e. MHO+QHO+interaction is a constant.This can be checked with the following code

```
e1[t_] := g1*(Abs@asol[t])^2;
e2[t_] := Chop[csol[t].(d1 + 0.5*d0).Conjugate[csol[t]]];
eint[t_] := 
  Chop[csol[t].(g2*(Re@asol[t])*(d2 + d3)).Conjugate[
    csol[t]]];
etotal[t_] := e1[t] + e2[t] + eint[t];
{etotal[0], etotal[tbar]}
```

Energy conservation begins to fail as I go to g2=0.5 (try g2=0.1 for a more dramatic demonstration of this).

Comment: For `g1=0.5;g2=1` I get a solution in about 5 seconds in _v12.3_. Which version are you in?

Comment: @xzczd I'm running 11.3 and yes I can get the solution too, I don't trust the solution because of the values which are getting pretty big. It gets worse if you took g1=0.1, g2=1 for example

Comment: What do you mean by "pretty big"? What's the expected amplitude? The initial value problem (IVP) solver for ODE in `NDSolve` is very robust and should always be the last thing to adjust. (Anyway, I tried adjusting `WorkingPrecision` to `16`, but the solution just looks the same: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwtUP.png) Are you sure the system itself is correct?

Comment: @xzczd I've now added some detail in the question on what I mean by too large. Let me know if this helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I'd like to emphasize again, the initial value problem (IVP) solver for ODE built in `NDSolve` is very robust and should always be the last thing to adjust, so please make sure the equation system itself is correct.

Anyway, let alone the correctness of system, if you care about the invariant, consider `Projection` method (The following takes about 350 seconds on my laptop for `g1 = 0.1; g2 = 1;`):

```
invar = g1*(Abs@a[t])^2 + c[t] . (d1 + 0.5*d0) . Conjugate[c[t]] + 
  c[t] . (g2*(Re@a[t])*(d2 + d3)) . Conjugate[c[t]]
solinvar = 
 NDSolve[{a'[t] == -I (g1*a[t] + g2/2 c[t] . (d2 + d3) . Conjugate[c[t]]), 
   c'[t] == -I*c[t] . (d1 + 0.5*d0 + g2*(Re@a[t]) (d2 + d3)), initc, initq}, {a, 
   c}, {t, 0, tbar}, 
  Method -> {"Projection", Method -> "ImplicitRungeKutta", "Invariants" -> invar}, 
  MaxSteps -> Infinity]

Plot[invar /. sol // Evaluate, {t, 0, tbar}]
```

[image]

Still, it's not perfectly conserved, but much better than the default. For comparison:

```
solref = NDSolve[{a'[t] == -I (g1*a[t] + g2/2 c[t] . (d2 + d3) . Conjugate[c[t]]), 
     c'[t] == -I*c[t] . (d1 + 0.5*d0 + g2*(Re@a[t]) (d2 + d3)), initc, initq}, {a, 
     c}, {t, 0, tbar}, MaxSteps -> Infinity]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {33.922384, Null} *)

Plot[invar /. solref // Evaluate, {t, 0, tbar}]
```

[image]

However, I doubt if this really makes sense, given that this solution is virtually the same as the one given by default method:

```
Plot[ReIm@a[t] /. {solinvar[[1]], solref[[1]]} // Evaluate, {t, 0, tbar}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Dashed, Dashed}]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for doing this comparison with another method. It is helpful to see it in this light. I agree that holding something constant like this feels artificial and does not change the solution much anyway.